# Px and dp to position a view

Tags: android

I read so much about dp and px and the using dp should be the right way. My question is, lets say you want to load a an image.png into an imageview using wrap content parameter. Lets say that this you want to place a text in a specific part of the image. I add a text view on top of the image view. Now my question, in order to position the text correct, do I use px or dp? I don't want the text to be outside the allocated area on different screen sizes and desnsities

Thanks

As suggested, I am attaching a sample design of what I am doing. I have a designer who provided me with the dialog box (in a png image) as the image below. I would like to place title text in the white box above. In my eclipse, I positioned it using dp and it looks perfect. When Irun it on my phone. It is great. I am worried about different phones. Would it look the same ? Should I use px instead? Is absolute positioning like this the wrong way of doing things?

[image]

Comment: My worry is that image is being done as wrap content.. Wouldn't the image dimension be as if px was supplied? Therefore I could be using different units

Comment: AFAIK, your drawable resources scale after the screen density, and so does dp. I'm not certain, hence this is a comment and not an answer